# Uncommenting code with sed

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I'm writing a script that would uncomment a few lines of code from a file. This is what I'm trying to uncomment:

```
#export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

So I did my research and found this command that does what I'm looking for:

```
sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#//g' file
```

So how would I adjust it to do what I'm looking for? I've tried pasting the text inside the command, did my best to escape the all the quotes, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `<pattern>` is just a placeholder for a regular expression to match the lines (and *only* those lines) you want to uncomment. Unfortunately, it's hard to say what that expression should be; the two lines shown don't have much in common, and we don't know what other lines you *don't* want to match might appear in the file. It might be easier to replace `/<pattern>/` with a numeric range (like `6,7`) to match the line numbers you want to uncomment.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the `<pattern>`. Also, It's not necessary for me  to uncomment both lines in one command.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, what *exactly* did you try? What do you mean it didn't *seem* to work? It either uncommented the desired lines or it didn't.

Comment: Can you give us the actual pattern that you tried. Otherwise it's hard for us to guess what went wrong. Did you try to use the entire line as pattern?

Comment: @ThomasKühn That's exactly what I did (well, except for escaping the quotes)

Comment: well, your pattern then includes the `/`-sign, which you need to escape as well, i.e. try: `sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#//g' file`, with the pattern `#export PATH="$HOME\/.rbenv\/bin:$PATH"`. You don't need to escape the double quotes, because you use single quotes in your sed expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are for *comments*, not flow control.

Instead of trying to modify the file to toggle those lines, control their execution via an environment variable.

```
if [[ -v enable_ruby ]]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Now, if the variable `enable_ruby` is set to *any* value in the environment, `PATH` will be modified and `ruby` configured. Otherwise, those two lines are ignored.

```
$ bash myScript                # Don't do the ruby stuff
$ enable_ruby=1 bash myScript  # Do the ruby stuff
$ export enable_ruby=          # The empty string is sufficient
$ bash myScript                # Do the ruby stuff
$ unset enable_ruby
$ bash myScript                # Don't do the ruby stuff
```

Comment: I agree with your statement, but I can't think of a way to do this. The file I'm editing is `.zshrc` (a file that gets executed every time I open a new terminal instance). So if I want the `enable_ruby` variable to be set to something, I would set it in the same file. However, it would have to precede your mentioned statement and that's where I see the problem.

Comment: There are several files that get sourced prior to `.zshrc`, the most relevant being `.zshenv`; just add `export enable_ruby=1` to it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to carefully and laboriously escape your pattern for `sed` as @Thomas Kühn points out.

The alternative to work smarter, not harder, and see if you can mark up the lines beforehand:

```
#export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"   # setrbpath
#eval "$(rbenv init -)"                 # runrbinit
```

Now you can just `sed -i -e '/setrbpath/s/^#//' file` and it'll be stable against small modifications to the template file.

Answer (score 0):

To do this job robustly just use awk with string operations. Given these input files:

```
$ cat file1
#export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#eval "$(rbenv init -)"

$ cat file2
This is what I'm trying to uncomment:

#export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#eval "$(rbenv init -)"

So I did my research and found this command that does what I'm looking for
```

This is all you need:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{sub(/./,"")} 1' file1 file2
This is what I'm trying to uncomment:

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

So I did my research and found this command that does what I'm looking for
```

or if the target strings could appear mid-line instead of always as the whole line:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if (s=index($0,i)) $0=substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+1)} 1' file1 file2
This is what I'm trying to uncomment:

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

So I did my research and found this command that does what I'm looking for
```

The above will work no matter what characters the target strings contain.